# Tomcat Deploying old jars from shared\lib

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I am using tomcat\shared\lib for storing jars of my application. When i put new jars the  new changes are not getting loaded . It seems new jars are not getting redeployed. Application is showing old jars functionality.

Thanks,
Bhupendra K.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm redeploying, I tend to wipeout the  contents of the webapps and work directories, in some attempt to clean up old jars.

It might help..

Answer (score 0):

Only jars in /WEB-INF/lib are redeployed. You should not store application jars in /shared/lib .